# how to reach parent of parent directory?

Tags: command-line

`.` is used to refer to current directory

`..` refers to the parent directory

how to reach the directory just above `..` ?

i am asking because i am trying to use `COPY` command in a dockerfile and i need to copy data from the local  `.../app`  to the container working directory but don't know how to reach that parent of parent of curent directory `...`

i don't want to use the absolute path, any help ?

*tree* :

```
src
 |------ app
 |------ par2
           |----- par1         
                   |---- dockerfile
```

Comment: There can be used in a __Windows__ batch file `echo Current directory "%CD%"` or `for %%I in (.) do echo Current directory "%%~fI"` to get output which directory is the current directory on execution of the batch file. There can be used in the __Windows__ batch file also `cd ..\..` to change the current directory __two__ directories up in directory tree from the current directory. ``..\`` can be used as often as needed inside a path of a directory/file and even everywhere and not just at the beginning. Example: `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\..\..\inf` is the same as just `%SystemRoot%\inf`.

Answer (score 0):

try:   `../..`

You can use the expression multiple times. Just have to add another /

Comment: tried it but ddidn't work

Comment: If you give me the absolute paths where you start from and where you want to go I can help further. However, ./../../ points to the parent directory of the current parent.